# Difference between Manifest.xml and Config.xml in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing my phonegap application in Eclipse on Android platform and i want to create .APK file from Adobe's account(build.phonegap.com)

So, my problem is that **i don't know the difference between Manifest.xml file and config.xml file.**

**In which file i have to add permissions for my phonegap application(In manifest or in config file)??**

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 files - one is `AndroidManifest.xml`, the other `config.xml`.

The first file - `AndroidManifest.xml` - is used to set up information about your application, the main activity (Java class) it uses to actually run, permissions and more-less everything Android-related. This file is only for use on Android devices (not iOS, nor BlackBerry etc.).

`config.xml` on the other hand is PhoneGap-specific and contains information to set up your PhoneGap project. You set up plugins, allowed URLs that PhoneGap can access and few other settings here.

Comment: OKie....if i put my all uses permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, then it will be worked on other devices like on iOS, Blackberry??

Comment: no, permissions are set up differently for each system - check out the [PhoneGap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/index.html), where each functionality has info about permissions and where to put them

Comment: as for building your app online - I've never tried to actually build it that way, so you'll need to research or experiment a bit and see what works there

Comment: So, what is the difference between <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/> in config.xml and <uses-permission android-name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> in android???? Can you explain me...